# phpMyAdmin is much slower with a query than running the same query via command line

Tags: phpmyadmin

I try to run some view query. When I run it from command line it takes 1 second, but when I run it via phpMyAdmin it takes lot of time. It may even take a few minutes.

I try in phpMyAdmin version 5.1.3, and also in 4.9.10.

I see i the process list that the following query run multiple because the time column every time is 0.
`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'`